# Merging three dataframes in R based on condition in the first dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to merge three dataframes based on a simple condition in the first dataframe.

```
df1 <- data.frame("id" = c("1001","1002","1003", "1004", "1005"),
                  "var1" = c(1,2,1,2,2))

df2 <- data.frame("id" = c("1001","1002","1003", "1004", "1005"),
                  "var2" = c(121,334,565,77,12))

df3 <- data.frame("id" = c("1001","1002","1003", "1004", "1005"),
                  "var2" = c(341,601,561,221,9))
```

I want to merge df2 into df1 based on id when var1=1, and df3 into df1 when var1=2. So it should look like:

```
df4 <- data.frame("id" = c("1001","1002","1003", "1004", "1005"),
                  "var1" = c(1,2,1,2,2),
                  "var2" = c(121,601,565,221,9))
```

Ideally I would like to do this with dplyr, so I was thinking something like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df4 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "id") %>%
  filter(var == 1)
```

but that actually works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `var1` columns to `df2` and `df3` that can match `var1` in `df1`, you could try the following.

```
library(dplyr)

df2$var1 <- 1
df3$var1 <- 2

left_join(df1, bind_rows(df2, df3), by = c("id", "var1"))
```

**Output**

```
    id var1 var2
1 1001    1  121
2 1002    2  601
3 1003    1  565
4 1004    2  221
5 1005    2    9
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a bit less elegant than I was hoping but works haha